# c# GridView RowDataBound Error

Tags: c#, gridview, rowdatabound

I have a gridview that should be editable when a row is clicked. This gridview is clickable in a row so when I clicked it, the row will be displayed in other pages for editing reason. I got an error like this

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: index.

This is happening for this line:

```
LinkButton _singleClickButton = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[1].Controls[1];
```

How can I fix this?

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // Get reference to button field in the gridview.  
            LinkButton _singleClickButton = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[1].Controls[1];
            string _jsSingle = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(_singleClickButton, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
            e.Row.Style["cursor"] = "hand";
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = _jsSingle;
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Which is it? Controls[0] or Controls[1]?

Comment: Why do you feel that its `Control[1]`, can't you not use `FindControl`

Comment: @V4Vendetta I used Control[0] initially but doesn't work. How to use FindControl, can you throw some samples? Thank:D

Comment: @Edwin the first one. Still got error like before

Answer (score 0):

You should be using something like `e.Row.FindControl("linkbuttonid")`. This will get you the required link button from the current row, then you can attach your handlers to the same and perform your logic